# SwiftUI | VStack won't work inside of ForEach Loops

Tags: swift, xcode, foreach, swiftui

I'm using a ForEach loop to display different bars with numbers underneath them to display a graph. However, I can't seem to use a VStack inside of the ForEach loop inside of an HStack to display multiple bars next to each other, all with a number underneath.

```
HStack{
    ForEach(0 ..< 7) {
        VStack {
            Capsule().frame(width: 30, height: 200)
            Text("\($0 + 1)")
        }                        
    }
}
```

I've tried using moving the VStack outside of the ForEach loop but this results in the bars being displayed below each other. How can I display the number underneath the bar whilst arranging the multiple bars next to each other?

Comment: Can you show a pic of your issue and your goal? I think your codes working ok for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works with small fix - added explicit parameter for `ForEach`. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
HStack {
    ForEach(0 ..< 7) { i in
        VStack {
            Capsule().frame(width: 30, height: 200)
            Text("\(i + 1)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LoL, I wanted Answer the same code, but I was not sure if he knows about i-index or not? And I was thinking to real issue